# С чего начать большой веб-проект?

Tags: agile, scrum

Тематика e-commerce.
Проект достаточно большой, но согласно методикам "гибкой разработки", надо разбить проект на спринты в 1-2 недели каждый.

Каждый спринт должен заканчиваться вполне рабочей версией продукта, пусть и с очень ограниченным функционалом. После каждого спринта этот функционал будет становиться шире. Вроде бы все понятно.

Но что-то я застопорился с началом. Как начинаю расписывать задачу для спринта по функционалу, так сразу понимаю, что двумя неделями тут даже и не пахнет. Минимум месяц, а то и два!

Как обычно поступают в студиях, работающих по такой методике?
Быть может накидать интерфейс на "бумажке" и начать с этого(с front-end)?
Или с головой окунуться в самое сложное из функционала - и реализовывать это?
Или сразу сесть и начать продумывать структуру БД? (но есть опасность, что что-нибудь важно упущу, а потом всю структуру переделывать заного).
Как же выстроить канбан?

Comment: Так по аджайлу никто не планирует дальше одного спринта - тяп-ляп и в продакшен и так итерация за итерацией пока у заказчика деньги не закончатся. ;-)

Comment: @cpp_user это был не прораб^W ненастоящий аджайл. просто многие неправильно понимают слово over в agile manifest. и начинается "мы же готовы к изменениям, следование плану нам не нужно".

Comment: Любые изменения ведут к пересмотру планов...

Comment: @cpp_user да, только в моем случае - заказчик и исполнитель я сам) тяп-ляп не покатит, хочу результата

Comment: @Павел Краснов: Тогда какие проблемы? Почему вы боитесь что БД нужно будет подправить?

Comment: @cpp_user горький опыт. Делали с товарищем один проект просто на php без фреймворков писали. Вроде и mvc старались использовать. Но в итоге, через какое-то время, проект стал слишком проблемным для развития. Все из-за того, что вначале проект решал лишь одну задачу и было все просто, а когда он разросся, то любые более или менее важные изменения в программе влекли цепную реакцию и кучу работы по изменению всего и вся. Мы потом в конце концов этот проект просто решили переписать заного. Но сил затрачено было...

Comment: Скорее не было модульности, разделения логики и представления.

Comment: @cpp_user и тестов...

Comment: @cpp_user лучше уж пересматривать планы, чем вообще их не иметь

Comment: Поддерживать актуальность тестов в динамично изменяющемся проекте может дорого стоить и по времени и по деньгам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основная суть скрама - максимизировать обратную связь, не слишком отвлекая при этом разработчиков. Ради этого вводят итерации. Суть итерации - получение [инкремента](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#artifacts-increment) - **пригодного к использованию** приращения продукта. Пригодность к использованию (готовность) - это основной критерий.  Потому что только то, что можно использовать, может дать настоящую, качественную обратную связь.

Прототип - дает обратную связь. Схема базы - вообще никак.

Учтите, что скрам - это методология для команд от 5 до 9 человек. Целиком он вам он не нужен.

Для команд из одного человека готовых методологий нет. Делайте в том порядке, в котором вам удобнее.

Единственное, что я бы вам посоветовал (раз совсем не знаете, за что схватиться) - начинать не с интерфейса или базы. А с расписывания основных user story. Выберите из них самые важные, и реализуйте одну за одной (дописывая по необходимости **тесты**, базу и код).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Для одного человека scrum тоже подходит. Прежде всего тем, что за счет быстрой разработки прототипа  можно быстрее получить обратную связь. А то на первых парах разработка продукта без отзывов - как блуждание ежика в тумане - вроде идешь на "звук", а оказывается это всего лишь "эхо".

Comment: @ПавелКраснов да, многие практики из скрама - подходят, просто чисто технически это будет не скрам (вы же не будете проводить дейли-митинги :) На самом деле любая agile-методология - это набор практик. Сами по себе многие из них применимы вне зависимости от размера команды.

Answer (score 3):

По своему опыту могу сказать, что создание проекта начинается с дня х. В этот день запускаешь yEd и прорисовываешь в нём всё что ты будешь делать буквально до мелочей. Сразу же увидите какие задачи перед вами стоят. Не только визуализируете цель, но и сразу увидите все дырявые места и на что уйдёт время. Зачастую случалось даже так, что либо находились иные решения, либо менялм структуру или логику работы проекта. Главное всё продумать, ровно на столько на сколько возможно, так как переделывать что-то потом стоит огромного времени и денег.

Считай это как запуск ракеты, а ты инженер. Вроде и просчитать нужно а вроде и спешить не надо, так как ошибёшься не взлетит. Но главное на самом деле - это тест и полёт. Опыт полученный в процессе создания проекта даже лучше открывает на всё глаза нежели многонедельные обдумывания.

По поводу с чего начать? Всегда необходимо начинать с сердцевины. Просто спрашиваешь себя будет ли Х работать без У? Если нет пишешь У. Потом будет ли Н работать без Z если нет то пишешь Z и наоборот. Таким способом найдёшь то с чего нужно начать. Бери в пример вконтакте. Написали соц сеть, написали страницы вход выход, регистрация, забыли пароль. запустились. прикрутили фотографии. прикрутили новости. в процессе работы поняли каким должен быть софт и написали KPHP.

Удачи в проекте.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Честно говоря, проекты я так никогда не прорисовывал. Делал обычно обычные таблицы и связи между ними - но это проектирование бд, совсем другое. Как я понял, вы мне как и @PashaPash советуете проработать для начала user story, и накидать минимальный функционал для самого главного. Понемногу в голове проясняется все.

Comment: В любом случае прорисовать всё - очень полезно. Я сам в это когда-то не верил. Но потом попробовав, когда делаешь всё по продуманному плану не только эффективность возрастает в разы, но и делаешь всё быстрее. Знаешь что будет потом и не держишь кучу всего в голове. А чистая голова сами знаете как важна.

Comment: @ilago: `написали KPHP` И благополучно [забросили](https://github.com/vk-com/kphp-kdb/commits/master) :)

Answer (score 1):

Если проект большой, то может и не получиться на первых этапах создавать прототипы.

Следует помнить, что чем позже после начала реализации проекта вносится изменение, тем оно дороже по трудозатратам. Поэтому имеет смысл вначале углубиться в проектирование - расписать все варианты использования по пунктам (что куда нажимает пользователь, что делает система в ответ на его действия). Это муторно и долго, но чем подробнее будет расписано, тем проще потом будет составить по всему этому правильную структуру БД и всего приложения в целом. Станет понятна вся логика работы приложения.

После этого этапа проектирования выбираешь любой (ну или наиболее приоритетный/интересный/базовый) вариант работы с системой (к примеру авторизацию) и делаешь ее. Потом выбираешь и делаешь следующий. У тебя как раз будут получаться работающие прототипы, которые урезаны по функционалу, а так же список "кусочков" программы, которые еще осталось сделать.

Каюсь, я лично не работал в крупных студиях, но в общем и целом порядок разработки чего-либо такой - сперва все спроектировать, чтобы не упустить важных деталей, а потом поочередная реализация сценариев использования. И по рассказам знакомых, в крупных компаниях делают так же, причем проектирование занимает не один месяц. А пока не спроектируют более-менее до конца - прототипы делать не пытаются ибо себе дороже.

Comment: все подробно спроектировать, а потом все реализовать (а потом протестировать и задеплоить) - это старый добрый водопад. это **полная противоположность** аджайлу )

Comment: Согласен, тут я накосячил и написал не совсем в тему ответ. С другой стороны, если взять только третий абзац из моего ответа, получится примерно что-то похожее на аджайл.

Comment: кстати, автор водопада - Winston Royce - первоначально предлагал итерационный подход, но его просто [*не так поняли*](https://vimeo.com/18951935)